# React Native webview page refresh issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I have 2 identical screens accessed using 2 different navigation methods. The first navigation method (stack) works, the second (drawer) does not.  The scenario and issue: -

**Stack Navigation Method**

The source url for the webview is not available (the server is not turned on). I navigate from the home screen to the webview screen. The first time around the activity indicator shows the page is trying to load for a number of seconds before the error HTML page is loaded. I navigate back to the home screen. I navigate for a second time to the webview screen. *The activity indicator shows the page is trying to load for a number of seconds before the error HTML page is loaded again.*

Console log: -

[image]

**Drawer Navigation Method**

The source url for the webview is not available (the server is not turned on). I navigate from the home screen to the webview screen. The first time around the activity indicator shows the page is trying to load for a number of seconds before the error HTML page is loaded. I navigate back to the home screen. I navigate for a second time to the webview screen. *The error HTML is immediately loaded without attempting to access the source url.*

The console log: -

[image]

I have turned the source url on between navigation's to be sure it's not looking and I've tried a state change in the useFocusEffect by adding a random number to the end of the url ([http://192.168.4.1/wifi?\](http://192.168.4.1/wifi?%5C)<randomnumber>) but it's made no difference.

The code: -

**Stack Navigation Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { HomeScreen } from './ui/homescreen.js';
import { WebScreen } from './ui/webscreen.js';

export const App = () => {

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home Screen">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home Screen" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Web Screen" component={WebScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );

}

export default App;
```

**Drawer Navigation Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerToggleButton } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import { HomeScreen } from './ui/homescreen.js';
import { WebScreen } from './ui/webscreen.js';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const HomeDrawer = () => {

    const SideMenu = () => {
        return (
            <DrawerToggleButton />
        )
    }

    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home Screen"
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: true,
                headerLeft: false,
                headerRight: SideMenu,
            }}
        >
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home Screen" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Web Screen" component={WebScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );

}

export const App = () => {

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home">
                    {(props) => (
                        <HomeDrawer {...props} />
                    )}
                </Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );

}

export default App;
```

**Home Screen**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Web Screen")} style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
                <Text>Go to Web Screen</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    );

}
```

**Webview Screen**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Pressable, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

export function WebScreen({ route, navigation }) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(route));

    const ErrorHTML = require('./webviewerror.html');
    const [source, setSource] = React.useState({ uri: 'http://192.168.4.1/wifi' });

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            console.log("useFocusEffect source = " + JSON.stringify(source));
        }, [])
    );
        
    return (
        <WebView
            style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 }}
            ref={(ref) => (this.webview = ref)}
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            source={source} 
            startInLoadingState={true}
            renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }} size="large" />}
            onError={(syntheticEvent) => {
                const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
                console.log('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
                setSource(ErrorHTML);
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end.

I discovered unmountOnBlur and added it to the Drawer Navigation Code as follows: -

```
<Drawer.Screen name="Web Screen" component={WebScreen}
    options={{
        unmountOnBlur: true,
    }}
/>
```